# SSH between 2 PCs

Tags: ssh

I've successfully managed to setup SSH server individually on 2 PCs(master and slave setup).

I can login from the slave to the master but the vice versa isn't happening.

From he individual PCs I can login to the localhost also.

Can someone help me out? I've disabled the firewalls and tried everything. Should I provide more specific details regd this?

I've installed the openssh-server on both PCs already. And I'm using the above mentioned syntax. Also, the error message I'm getting is:

> ssh uname@10.5.10.251 ssh: connect to host 10.5.10.251 port 22: Connection refused

Whereas this works perfectly fine when I ssh from the slave.

On trying ssh -v I get:

> OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-7ubuntu1, OpenSSL 1.0.0e 6 Sep 2011
>
> debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
>
> debug1: Applying options for *
>
> debug1: Connecting to 10.5.10.251 [10.5.10.251] port 22.
>
> debug1: connect to address 10.5.10.251 port 22: Connection refused
>
> ssh: connect to host 10.5.10.251 port 22: Connection refused

And pinging the slave from master works fine. This means that master is able to reach slave, right? Also, I've disabled the firewall on the slave using the UI.

Comment: what is the error message you are getting when you can't login?

Comment: Run SSH with the `-v` flag and update your answer. A few things could be going wrong here, either your computer is not finding the other computer on the network, the other computer isn't running the openssh-server on port 22, or the other computer could have a firewall like ufw blocking traffic.

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed SSH servers through apt-get via `$ apt-get install openssh-server` on **both** servers, you should be able to access them both ways with their respective IP addresses.

If you have only on one PC a SSH server, and you try the other one without a SSH server, it will obviously not work.

Also be sure to respect the target machine's username you try to connect with: `$ ssh username@192.168.1.245`.

Comment: If your question isn't answered to your satisfaction, then please edit your question and be way more precise what you have done, etc.

Comment: Thanks all! I'd installed the openssh-server on both PCs already. And I'm using the above mentioned syntax.

Also, the error message I'm getting is:
ssh root@10.5.10.251
ssh: connect to host 10.5.10.251 port 22: Connection refused

Whereas this works perfectly fine when I ssh from the slave.